# Ubuntu 10.04 problems - GVIM and Sound

Tags: audio, gvim, ubuntu-10.04, gvimrc

Well, i have 2 problems .. not exactly problems, but one is a question, and the other is a problem .

QUESTION
I have installed gVim on my laptop and now i want to install plugins and customize my vimrc . Where is the 'plugin' , 'color' , 'docs' directory located in order for me to drop those files in ? And where do i need to put the .vimrc file for gVim to be able to recogonize it ?

PROBLEM
Sound isn't working. I dont know whats the problem @ all. It just doesnt play . And NO its not on mute. i Checked. If any other input is required from the terminal , please ask for it. I'm kinda a n00b in all this.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be on SuperUser.

Comment: StackOverflow is for _programming_ questions. Any other computer related questions are welcome on superuser.com

Comment: I'm so sorry. My bad

Comment: separate both questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop your .vimrc on your user home folder with your configuration. I usually create a .vimrc in my home pointing to a .vim directory.

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/after,$VIMRUNTIME
source ~/.vim/.vimrc
```

...so, in this .vim dir, I put color, docs and such. I create a .vimrc in .vim where actually all my configuration is.

About sound problems, I think you should post it at Ubuntu Forums and seek for help, or provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Read the :help for vimrc and 'rtp'.  It will tell you what the default location of your personal vim config and runtime is.  For Unix, ~/.vimrc and ~/.vim; for Windows, $HOME/_vimrc and $HOME/vimfiles.